# Adobe Livecycle javascript get attribute node

Tags: javascript, pdf, livecycle

I have a PDF template that I am designing in Livecycle Designer ES2. The data binding is XML Schema. For one of the fields I need to bind the data with some formatting.
For example: If my XML (based on the schema) is as follows:

```
<formElement xmlns:ns2="http://it.anas.pdm/anaspcm">
    <elementNode value="FCON" />
</formElement>
```

How can I access to the `value` attribute?

I tried with:

> xfa.data.formElement.elementNode.getAttribute("value");

but it don't work.

Do you know help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally this should work:

```
xfa.resolveNode("formElement.elementNode.value")
```